# I am not able make use of elvis operator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, elvis-operator

I am not able to use ?: operator in Kotlin. It still doesn't make sense to me how and when should we use it.
Can anyone please let me know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a scenario, where you need the **length of a username**.
Now, the username itself could be null for different reasons and you’ll get the famous **NullPointerException** if you try to get the length from this username - which is null. This is not a good user experience.

But if somehow, when the username is null, we could return some integer values, then our app would not crash!

In this type of cases, we can make use of **Elvis operator (?:)**.

Here’s a code snippet:

```
var username: String? = null
```

```
fun main() {
    val firstResult: Int = username!!.length //Gives NPE and the app crashes
    println(firstResult)

    val secondResult: Int = username?.length ?: -1 //By using ?: operator, the app survives with -1 value
    println(secondResult)
}
```

The **left** side of **?: operator** will be considered if it is **non-null**.
But if it is **null**, then the **right** side of **?: operator** will be executed.

This is how **Elvis operator (?:)** works.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Now this makes total sense to me. @SayanSubhraBanerjee